# contour characters in a image, Car plate - OpenCv

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, k-means

im using opencv under python to read a car plate
the code bellow work fine

```
_,thresh = cv2.threshold(Cropped,70,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(3,3))
dilated = cv2.dilate(thresh,kernel,iterations = 0)
contoursX, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

(contoursX, boundingBoxes) = contours.sort_contours(contoursX, method="left-to-right")
for contour in contoursX:
    [x,y,w,h] = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    cv2.rectangle(Cropped, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (90, 0, 255), 2)
    plt.imshow(Cropped, cmap="gray", vmin=0, vmax=255)
    plt.show()
```

as you can see, i alredy do a grayscale to the image and also crope it, the image in the code is `Cropped`

and this code is work well for me

[image]

however, in some cases the contour went wrong as you can see bellow :
[image]

the original picture (after croping and grayscale ) :

[image]

should i change the method attribtus in the contour function, or playing with the colors

i was also thinking if maybe do some clustering algorithm as k-means to cluster the nighbers, but no idea how or if it will work .

any help :D

**EDIT**
Oiginal  first image 
[image]

Original second image

[image]

Comment: Could you add your original image before any processing?

Comment: @nathancy thanks , i have edited my request

Comment: You should use adaptive threshold to properly extract the numbers in the car plate with intensity change

Comment: @yapws87 any link please ?

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=adaptivethreshold